# Grouping rows in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As shown in below if campaignIds are equal, I want to make them group. But I cant figure out how to do that. Group by CampaignId did not work.

[image]

Live example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb1dd/2

Comment: If you had normalized your design, this would a very easy statement...

Comment: normalizing for which one ?

Comment: which result do you want to achieve?

Comment: By this example I want to see one row for each CampaignId in the first result on the picture.

Comment: Regarding normalizing: if the table was defined as `(campaign_id, rate_nr, rate_value)` it would be a simple `select campaign_id, rate_nr, sum(rate_value) from campaign_rates group by campaign_id, rate_nr`

Comment: Table is already defined as Id,CampaignId, RateNumber,RateValue. I cannot  understand your point |: If I group by campaign_id, rate_nr, this time one row will be created for each different rate_nr.

Comment: -1 This is a very poor question - your initial table structure is not clear, nor is your desired outcome, while your description of the problem is self-contradictory. Try changing the question to **clearly** show (a) your current situation (eg. table structure, sample data) and (b) your desired outcome (eg. by including sample results from sample data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using the **pivot** feature in SQL Server, it may result in more readable SQL
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT CampaignId, [1] AS Rate1, [2] AS Rate2, [3] AS Rate3
FROM 
(SELECT CampaignId, RateNumber, RateValue
FROM CampaignRate) p
PIVOT
(
SUM (RateValue)
FOR RateNumber IN
( [1], [2], [3] )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.CampaignId;
    GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Should it get the sum of the rating per rate number? You can do it by using `Group By` on CampaignID and `SUM()` function.

```
select CampaignId,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 1 then RateValue else null end) as Rate1,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 2 then RateValue else null end) as Rate2,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 3 then RateValue else null end) as Rate3,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 4 then RateValue else null end) as Rate4,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 5 then RateValue else null end) as Rate5,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 6 then RateValue else null end) as Rate6,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 7 then RateValue else null end) as Rate7,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 8 then RateValue else null end) as Rate8,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 9 then RateValue else null end) as Rate9,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 10 then RateValue else null end) as Rate10,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 11 then RateValue else null end) as Rate11,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 12 then RateValue else null end) as Rate12,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 13 then RateValue else null end) as Rate13,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 14 then RateValue else null end) as Rate14,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 15 then RateValue else null end) as Rate15,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 16 then RateValue else null end) as Rate16,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 17 then RateValue else null end) as Rate17,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 18 then RateValue else null end) as Rate18,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 19 then RateValue else null end) as Rate19,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 20 then RateValue else null end) as Rate20,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 21 then RateValue else null end) as Rate21,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 22 then RateValue else null end) as Rate22,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 23 then RateValue else null end) as Rate23,
    sum(case when RateNumber = 24 then RateValue else null end) as Rate24
    from CampaignRate
group by CampaignId;
```

Check out the [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3715/1).